# Cannot output correct rows from DB after using an IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to create a tsql stored procedure which will output rows based on some parameters. The ultimate aim is to move the rows to another table which is why I have counts - I want to keep track of how many rows I am moving. There are two tables - `Notes` and `ExtraNotes`. The `ExtraNotes` holds overflow info from the first table.

I am using the `if` statement to select the correct rows based on the parameter called `NoteType` but I don't know how to output the correct select statement within the `if`. I know the select statement within each `if` is wrong

```
select * 
from dbo.Notes 
left join dbo.ExtraNotes on Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID 
where NoteDate <= @Date
```

Could anyone offer some pointers on how I can output the correct rows and possibly restructure this better?

The full code is here.

```
alter proc selectrows 
   --external variables
   @Date datetime,
   @NoteType varchar(2)
as
--internal variables
--Count variables, before any changes
declare @count_rowsBefore int
declare @count_Extra_rowsBefore int

--Count variables of selected rows to be moved

declare @count_SelectedRows int
declare @count_Extra_SelectedRows int

select @count_rowsBefore = count(*)
from dbo.Notes

select @count_Extra_SelectedRows = count(*)
from dbo.ExtraNotes


if(@NoteType= 'B')
begin
select @count_SelectedRows = count(dbo.Notes.NoteID), @count_Extra_SelectedRows =            count(dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID)
        from dbo.Notes
        left join dbo.ExtraNotes on
        Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
        where NoteDate <= @Date

        select *
        from dbo.Notes
        left join dbo.ExtraNotes on
        Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
        where NoteDate <= @Date
end
else if(@NoteType = 'S')
  begin
  select @count_SelectedRows = count(dbo.Notes.NoteID), 
@count_Extra_SelectedRows = count(dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID)
        from dbo.Notes
        left join dbo.ExtraNotes on
        Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
        where NoteDate <= @Date
        and NoteType = 'S'

        select *
        from dbo.Notes
        left join dbo.ExtraNotes on
        Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
        where NoteDate <= @Date
end
else if (@NoteType = 'M')
begin
select @count_SelectedRows = count(dbo.Notes.NoteID),
@count_Extra_SelectedRows =  count(dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID)
        from dbo.Notes
        left join dbo.ExtraNotes on
        Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
        where NoteDate <= @Date
        and NoteType = 'M'

        select *
        from dbo.Notes
        left join dbo.ExtraNotes on
        Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
        where NoteDate <= @Date
  end
 else
  begin
  raiserror('Please enter a valid Note Read Type= M, S or B',16,1)
  end

Print 'Total Number of rows: ' + cast(@count_rowsBefore as varchar(10))
Print 'Total Number of "Extra" rows: ' + cast(@count_Extra_RowsBefore as varchar(10))

Print '-----------------------------------------------'
Print 'Total Number of rows to Move: ' + cast(@count_SelectedRows as varchar(10))
Print 'Total Number of "Extra" Rows to Move: ' + cast(@count_Extra_SelectedRows 
as varchar(10))
```

[Output screenshot](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y19/_karma_/code/ouput.png)

Comment: I feel like using a function that returns a table would serve you better than a stored procedure here.  Checkout table-valued functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do here, what's wrong with what you already have, and what you are asking us to do?

Comment: When I run this with the parameter of M for example I get rows back with Notetype M and S which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to do. It seems that you are looking for both the data, and some statistics about the data, but we don't know what data you actually want, or what the structure should be. Would it be easier to split these into seperate peice of logic? It may be simpler to map out what data you want output, and build code for each item seperately.

You could clarify if you could give a couple lines with columns and sample data, and the sample output you would like if that data was run through your code.

One suggestion, 
If/then statements do not filter anything, so you will get back more data than you want in the second query, as the filter only applies to each query individually. If this makes sense to you: you already have a variable with the NoteType you can use to filter. This filters the data correctly, and should replace the entire set of if-else if statements, since the code now uses the variable to select the right data directly. So instead of using if statements, you can use

```
select @count_SelectedRows = count(dbo.Notes.NoteID), 
        @count_Extra_SelectedRows =  count(dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID)
  from dbo.Notes left join dbo.ExtraNotes 
    on Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
  where NoteDate <= @Date
  and NoteType = @NoteType

select * 
  from dbo.Notes left join dbo.ExtraNotes 
    on Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID         
  where NoteDate <= @Date and NoteType = @NoteType
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are only two categories of note type- M for manual and S system. B stands for "both" in my head, but should never be entered to that column. I will try add in some sample data now to the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want counts with your rows you could use the OVER clause to generate them.  If NoteType can only be S or M in the table, then passing a NULL and using ISNULL(, ) should get what you want.  The code below pulls all notes, all related notes, and the first two columns are overall counts of source rows from each table.  I know this is example code, so I won't get all twitchy about the select *.

The link at bottom goes over the OVER clause.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selectRows
    ( @Date DATETIME
      , @NoteType VARCHAR(2) -- Pass NULL for both
    )
AS
    select count(dbo.notes.noteid) 
               over() as notecount
           , count(dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID)
               over() as extraNoteCount
           , *
    from dbo.Notes 
    left join dbo.ExtraNotes
        on Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
    where NoteDate <= @Date
      and NoteType = ISNULL(@NoteType, NoteType);
```

You don't necessarily need all of those copies of the counts, so unioning in a header row might be more what you had in mind.  The code below pulls all notes and a header row (noteid is null) with only counts:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selectRows
    ( @Date DATETIME
      , @NoteType VARCHAR(2) -- Pass NULL for both
    )
AS
    select *
       , CAST(NULL AS INT) noteCount
       , CAST(NULL AS INT) extraNoteCount
    from dbo.Notes 
    left join dbo.ExtraNotes
        on Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
    where NoteDate <= @Date
      and NoteType = ISNULL(@NoteType, NoteType)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL
       , NULL -- Repeat for as many columns as are in the select * above
       , count(dbo.Notes.NoteID)
       , count(dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID)
    from dbo.Notes 
    left join dbo.ExtraNotes
        on Notes.NoteID = dbo.ExtraNotes.NoteID
    where NoteDate <= @Date
      and NoteType = ISNULL(@NoteType, NoteType)
```

;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx